# Unable to find file during runtime execution at command prompt

Tags: java, jar, runtime

Good day to all experts here,

I am getting a FileNotFoundException when I run the following command at command prompt:

```
c:\TA\java -jar LoginCaptchaChrome.jar LoginCaptchaChrome https://2015.qa.int.www.mol.com/ C:\\TA\\TD\\Login\\Login.xlsx C:\\TA\\TR\\LoginCaptchaChrome_22082016_1838.xlsx
```

The error message is as below:

```
`Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\TA\TR\LoginCaptchaChrome_22082016_1838.xlsx" (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at LoginCaptchaChrome.main(LoginCaptchaChrome.java:58)
```

I am actually passing arguements from the command prompt, and the file

```
LoginCaptchaChrome_22082016_1838.xlsx` is not being passed to the code line :

FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("\"" + args[3] + "\"");
```

in the following code:

```
public class LoginCaptchaChrome {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException{
        String tc = args[0];
        String address = args[1];
        String test_data = args[2];
        String test_result = args[3];`

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\Lam Chio Meng\\Desktop\\work\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");     

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("\"" + args[3] + "\"");
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
```

Hope to have advice from experts here. Thank you in advance.

Comment: And does the file exist? You are trying to use it in the file output stream directly which assumes the file is already present on the disk

Comment: @nadir, Do correct me if I am wrong, but doesn't the the line `FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("filename") ` 's puspose is to create a new file ? That's what I observed when I was experimenting with this line on other project. When I debug it line by line, right after the execution of that FileOutputStream, the said file was created (in my case, it's an Excel file), although it's not openable. Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: Hmm, maybe this depends on the jvm version or OS version. Normally the FileOutputStream checks if given file is valid and then tries to open it - and opening is a native call which I guess can work differently

Comment: @Nadir, Thank you so much for your feedback. I'll keep that in mind as it add new perspective on how to approach FileOutputStrem. Thanks a bunch !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem comes from a misconception of how arguments are passed at a command line.

Take a shell for instance. Suppose this command at the prompt:

```
someCommand "arg with spaces"
```

What the arguments of the process actually are:

- `someCommand`, and
- `arg with spaces`. Yes, that's a single argument.

This means that the problem for you is this line:

```
new FileOutputStream("\"" + args[3] + "\"");
```

You don't need the leading and trailing quotes at all.

Moreover, since this is 2016, don't use `FileOutputStream`. Use JSR 203:

```
final Path path = Paths.get(args[3]);
final OutputStream out = Files.newOutputStream(path);
```

---

A simple way to see how the Java program actually sees arguments is a program like this:

```
public final class CmdLineArgs
{
    public static void main(final String... args)
    {
        final int len = args.length;

        System.out.println("---- Begin arguments ----");
        IntStream.range(0, len)
            .map(index -> String.format("Arg %d: %d", index + 1, args[index])
            .forEach(System.out::println);
        System.out.println("---- End arguments   ----");

        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Try and run this command at the prompt with, say:

```
java MyClass foo bar
```

and:

```
java MyClass "foo bar"
```

and see the difference.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback @fge. Just out of curiosity, I did try with `FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(args[3])；`, but I still end up with the same error. Was not that the correct way ? I will try out your suggestion on using JSR instead. Thank you so much again.

Comment: That won't be a problem of using the new file API here; the file is really missing. Are you sure about the order of arguments etc?

Comment: Hi @fge, thank you for your feedback. The order are correct as I verified this by printing out the arguments right before the execution of `FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(args[3])`  and args[3] does contain the data `C:\\TA\\TR\\LoginCaptchaChrome_22082016_1838.xlsx`. Anyway, I used your suggested method and it's working now. Thanks for your time and effort !